# How to loop Ranges in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbee in VBA, I have a problem that how to how to loop ranges in VBA
for example:
`Range("A1:D1").select`
to 
`Range("A100:D100").select`

or

`Range("A1:D1").select` to `Range("D1:G1").select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: it is better to avoid using `Select` , `Activate` , etc...

To loop through ranges that changes per row, use the `For` loop through `lRow` below:

```
' loop example per your case
For lRow = 1 To 100
    Range("A" & lRow & ":D" & lRow).Select
Next lRow
```

To loop through ranges that changes per column, use the `For` loop through `Col` below:

```
' loop example per your case
For Col = 1 To 4
    Range(Cells(1, Col), Cells(1, Col + 3)).Select
Next Col
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry for bothering again, here I have another question, how to loop `Range("A1")="=SUM(R[-3]C:R[-3]C)"`?

Comment: you need to use `Range("A" & lrow).FormulaR1C1` and in the formula to advance the `R` section

Comment: Feel really very sorry, actually I mean how to loop "=SUM(R[-3]C:R[-3]C)"?

Comment: @Stellera - If you are trying to place a formula in cell A1 that refers to row `R[-3]C` (i.e. column A in row **-2**) is not going to work - you will get a `#REF!` error.

Comment: Yeap,so is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: @Stellera I think you should create a new post, with the updated code, and what formula you want to have (you should include a sheet with the desired result in it), if you do, mark this as answer, as it did answer your original post (before you added the formula section). Or you can edit this post, and add all the information you want, and what formula you are trying to achieve. close this post, mark