# Duplicate a conditional macro to the next row xxx

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to find the way to duplicate this at the following rows. It has to go from C1:E1 than C2:E2 and so on.

```
Sub Conditional()
Conditional Macro
Range("C1:E1").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlUnique
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
   Color = -16383844
   TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
   Color = 13551615
   TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

I am very new to excel
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendations**

[Selects should be replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba); not addressing for color handling in the solution, but you may consider to change to a [RGB logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426369/set-background-colour-of-cell-to-rgb-value-of-data-in-cell) since themes may vary per user and the color may not be the one that you originally intended to. I will think that you need it in 2 different rulings as now (the duplicates in each column and not in the range).

**Solution**

```
Sub Exec_Conditional()
    Call Conditional(Range("C1:E1"))
    Call Conditional(Range("C2:E2"))
End Sub
Sub Conditional(RangeToPerform As Range)
    'if you need to have this condition only in the range, otherwise comment the delete line
    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions.Delete 
    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(RangeToPerform.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority: RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlUnique
    With RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844: .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic: .Color = 13551615: .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing the `.`'s in your With blocks (I know, copied from OP, but still...).  Also use of `Call` antiquated and never needed

Comment: My bad on that one thanks for spotting, I fixed it. OT: I use call just for my own standardization purposes to differentiate routines from functions, I haven't found documentation to prove that it's memory wasteful or related, the closest definition for usage that I have found somewhat explicative is at [this article](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/subroutines-call-keyword.htm)

Comment: Re `Call` - even that article acknowledges Call is regarded as obsolete (but then goes on to claim its use makes code more readable, one i dissagree with).  [Here's an opposing point of view](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ObsoleteCallStatement) [and another here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874163/445425)

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for your help, it is working great!
Is there any way that it's working as a loop? instead of adding a line [call] for each row?

Comment: There's a way yes, but you need to research about it to fit it to your [specific needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929553/how-to-loop-ranges-in-vba).