# passing loop variable in vba to ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range[...]

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I've problems passing variable *i* into a loop that selects chart source values.

```vb
    Sub Macro()
    
        For i = 2 To 10
        Windows("Book1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$F$2" _
            )
    
        Next i
    
    End Sub
```

I want to change the series value Sheet1!$A$**2**:$F$**2**" and put *i* value there -> Sheet1!$A$**i**:$F$**i**"

I tried different approaches, but they didn't work
[How to loop Ranges in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929553/how-to-loop-ranges-in-vba)
[Excel vba Charting, editting the range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703612/excel-vba-charting-editting-the-range)

```vb
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,("Sheet1!$A$" & i & ":$F$" & i)" _
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a workaround to my problem with selecting a value range differently.
Code below worked:

```
For i = 2 To 10
newName = "=Sheet1!$A$" + CStr(i)
newValues = "=Sheet1!$B$" + CStr(i) + ":$F$" + CStr(i)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = newName
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = newValues
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some unneeded quotes:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,Sheet1!$A$" & i & ":$F$" & i)
```

Comment: That didn't compile, formatting must be like shown in example

Range("Sheet1[...],Sheet1[...] " _
            )

Comment: Runs just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remember to assign *i* to str value

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,Sheet1!$A$" + cstr(i) + ":$F$" + cstr(i)
```

And the better way is createa variable

```
distinctrange = "Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,Sheet1!$A$" + cstr(i) + ":$F$" + cstr(i)
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(distinctrange)
```

Comment: That won't actually compile because you have the same issue as the OP with quotation marks.

Comment: Maybe brackets are exstras to. Updated answer

Comment: Syntax error  
`distinctrange = "Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,"Sheet1!$A$" + cstr(i) + ":$F$" + cstr(i)" `
`distinctrange = "Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,("Sheet1!$A$" + cstr(i) + ":$F$" + cstr(i))"`

Comment: `"Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,Sheet1!$A$" + cstr(i) + ":$F$" + cstr(i)` now it works

Comment: Yep it works, but how to pass it to the range function?
`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("distinctrange" _  </br>)`
Run-time error'1004:
Methon 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

And without quotas - Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(distinctrange _  </br> )`

Comment: Try first variant, with some edits: `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$" + cstr(i) + ":$F$" + cstr(i))`

Comment: It didn't worked. May I ask you to open new excel, create an empty chart and run macro code from open?

Comment: So, my friend, your question was about how to insert i into loop. We've done it by several ways. I can't use yor code because I did't see your file at all. Add screenshot or file and maybe I will be able to help you

Comment: Thank you @vovakirdan. I used your method passing with separate variables together with a different way to change chart values.

Comment: `distinctrange = "Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1,Sheet1!$A$" + cstr(i) + ":$F$" + cstr(i)` then `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(distinctrange)`